# Voltage droop and bulk capacitor selection

Tags: capacitor, pulse, bulk-capacitor

I have a fundamental question regarding bulk capacitor selection for a pulsed power circuit. Assuming I am switching a 2 kohms resistive load using a 2 kV power supply at a switching frequency of 10 kHz and 10% duty cycle. From my understanding, if I allow a 50 V droop in the main power supply, I have to use a bulk capacitor with a value of 500 uF at minimum (C = i*ton*delta V). What will happen if a 5 uF bilk capacitor is used instead? What will be the impact on the overall circuit performance?
Thanks.

Comment: 100x the voltage droop would exceed your supply, so you can expect the impact to be quite detrimental. Better decide what ripple you CAN tolerate and work from there.

Comment: Simulators are close to being your very best friend here.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \Delta V = {i \; t \over C} $$

You almost gave the formula for voltage change (hint, learn to use [MathJax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) on this forum), assuming constant current. All you need to do is plug in the new value of capacitance to find out the voltage droop. If you want to get more precise, use the RC discharge equation, however, in your situation the constant current model will be close enough.

You can also model this in SPICE using a resistor and capacitor. Use the .ic statement to set the voltage across the capacitor to 2kV.